# Generalize Get/Create Stored Procedure From One Item to Many

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have an express.js server running an application and from that server I can access or create "variant_id"s in PostgreSQL (Version 11) by using a stored procedure.

`SELECT(get_or_create_variant_id(info_about_variant));`

Sometimes I also need to get a bunch of these variant ids back by using a different stored procedure that takes multiple variants and returns multiple ids.

`SELECT(get_or_create_variant_ids([info_about_variant, info_about_another_variant]));`

What is the best way to generalize getting/creating a single id to doing multiple at once? I'm handling it in a LOOP in my stored procedure, but it feels like I should be able to use a JOIN instead.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_or_create_variant_id(
  variant_in VARIANT_TYPE
) RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE variant_id_out INTEGER;
BEGIN
  -- I'll be changing this to a ON CONFLICT block shortly
  SELECT(get_variant_id(variant_in) INTO variant_id_out);
  IF (variant_id_out IS NOT NULL) THEN
    RETURN variant_id_out;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO public.variant (
        [some_fields]
    )
      VALUES (
        [some_values]
      )
      RETURNING variant_id INTO variant_id_out;
    RETURN variant_id_out;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- What is the best way to avoid a loop here?
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_or_create_variant_ids(
  variants_in VARIANT_TYPE []
) RETURNS INT [] AS $$
DECLARE variant_ids_out INTEGER [];
DECLARE variants_in_length INTEGER;
DECLARE current_variant_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT (array_length(variants_in, 1) INTO variants_in_length);
  FOR i IN 1..variants_in_length LOOP
    SELECT(get_or_create_variant_id(variants_in[i]) INTO current_variant_id);
    SELECT(array_append(variant_ids_out, current_variant_id) INTO variant_ids_out);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN variant_ids_out;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Everything below is included for completeness, but probably less relevant to my question.
CREATE TYPE variant_type AS (
   [lots of info about the variant]
);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_variant_id(
  variant_in VARIANT_TYPE
) RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE variant_id_out INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT variant_id into variant_id_out
  FROM public.variant
  WHERE
     [I want them to]
  ;
  RETURN variant_id_out;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid explicit loop using builtin [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) - in this case, `unnest` function, and [array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_or_create_variant_ids_v2(
  variants_in VARIANT_TYPE []
)
RETURNS integer []
LANGUAGE sql AS $$
  SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT get_or_create_variant_id(u.v)
    FROM unnest(variants_in) AS u(v)
  )
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Ah! This is exactly what I'm looking for. It certainly gets rid of that stupid "i" counter, which was bugging me. Thanks for your help, appreciate it!